# SQL - Using Case Statements with Dynamic tables (unknown row count)

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, case

I'm having a bit of an issue with trying to create a stored procedure. I have 2 tables, `eTasks` and `eStaff`. The following are the columns for each table:

eTasks

```
TaskID | StaffID | Title | CreateDate
```

eStaff

```
StaffID | Name
```

Currently, as the data stands, all tasks are assigned to StaffID '1'.  Both `eTasks` and `eStaff` tables are updated with new tasks and Staff or they are taken out, these tables never have the same exact rows each day.  Some days, there will be a 1000 rows in `eTask` table and the next there could just be 400.  Some days there will be 3 staff members in the `eStaff` table and the next there could be 12.

What I would like to do is to evenly distribute the tasks among the current `StaffID`s when I run my stored procedure.

So far, this is what I have:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdatingeTasksTable 
AS
    DECLARE t_rowCount INTEGER
    DECLARE s_staffIDCount INTEGER

    SET t_rowCount = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM eTasks
    SET s_staffIDCount = SELECT DISTINCT StaffID FROM eStaff

    UPDATE eTasks
    SET StaffID = CASE 
                     WHEN TaskID % t_rowCount = 1 THEN 1
                     WHEN TaskID % t_rowCount = 2 THEN 4
                     WHEN TaskID % t_rowCount = 3 THEN 3
                     WHEN TaskID % t_rowCount = 4 THEN 2
                  END
    FROM eTasks b
    WHERE TaskID = b.TaskID;
```

I know, how my query currently is, it'll only divide up the tasks among 4 people.  Is there a way to make a CASE statement dynamic so that way there isn't just a set of static numbers?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit difficult in MySQL.  You can write a query to do this by adding a row number column:

```
select et.*, s.staffId
from (select count(*) as cnt
      from staff
     ) ss cross join
     (select et.*, (@rne := @rne + 1) as rn
      from etasks et cross join
           (select @rne := 0) params
     ) et join
     (select s.*, (@rns := @rns + 1) as rn
      from staff s cross join
           (select @rns := 0) params
     ) s
     on s.rn = mod(et.rn, ss.cnt) + 1;
```

You can then put this into an `update` using `join`:

```
update etask et join
       (select et.*, s.staffId
        from (select count(*) as cnt
              from staff
             ) ss cross join
             (select et.*, (@rne := @rne + 1) as rn
              from etasks et cross join
                   (select @rne := 0) params
             ) et join
             (select s.*, (@rns := @rns + 1) as rn
              from staff s cross join
                   (select @rns := 0) params
             ) s
             on s.rn = mod(et.rn, ss.cnt) + 1
       ) ets
       on et.taskid = ets.taskid
    set et.staffid = ets.staffid;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this test to work. I'm not using a stored proc, I'm just using user-defined variables in a MySQL session. But the same idea would work with local stored proc variables.

```
mysql> select count(*) into @staffcount from estaff; -- in my test this is 4

mysql> set @staffid = 0;
mysql> update etasks set staffid = (@staffid := (@staffid+1)%@staffcount)+1;

mysql> select * from etasks;
+--------+---------+-------+------------+
| taskid | staffid | title | createdate |
+--------+---------+-------+------------+
|      1 |       2 | NULL  | NULL       |
|      2 |       3 | NULL  | NULL       |
|      3 |       4 | NULL  | NULL       |
|      4 |       1 | NULL  | NULL       |
|      5 |       2 | NULL  | NULL       |
|      6 |       3 | NULL  | NULL       |
|      7 |       4 | NULL  | NULL       |
|      8 |       1 | NULL  | NULL       |
|      9 |       2 | NULL  | NULL       |
|     10 |       3 | NULL  | NULL       |
|     11 |       4 | NULL  | NULL       |
|     12 |       1 | NULL  | NULL       |
|     13 |       2 | NULL  | NULL       |
|     14 |       3 | NULL  | NULL       |
|     15 |       4 | NULL  | NULL       |
|     16 |       1 | NULL  | NULL       |
|     17 |       2 | NULL  | NULL       |
|     18 |       3 | NULL  | NULL       |
+--------+---------+-------+------------+
```

This does assume that your staffid values are known to go from 1 to the count of rows in estaff. If you want to map the values 1 to 4 to the respective rows in estaff, and assign the staffid's, here's a solution:

```
mysql> update etasks as t, 
    (select staffid, @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownum 
     from (select @rownum:=0) AS _init cross join estaff) as s 
  set t.staffid = s.staffid 
  where s.rownum = (@staffid := (@staffid+1)%@staffcount)+1;
```